# GZIP .htaccess and php session problem

Tags: php, session, .htaccess, gzip

I am trying to implement GZIP compression for my website. I copied the below code in my .htaccess file:

```
ExpiresActive On  
ExpiresDefault A604800  
Header append Cache-Control "public"  

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>  
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">  
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE  
</FilesMatch>  
</IfModule>
```

what happens is when I type username and password the page reloads but still the login form is displayed but session is set. When I refresh the page using ctrl + R the login form goes and the username is displayed. what will be the problem. wwaiting for ur reply.

Comment: regarding editing, You don't need to type `\`` before and after `<` and `>`, select the block and use 0101 button or short cut key Ctrl+K for code blocks or use `<pre>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I think it's mod_expires settings, not mod_gzip cause such behavior.

You just told your browser not to reload your page for the the week. It obeys.

I think you have to put expires settings at least inside of FilesMatch container. Or take any other sensible actions according to your real needs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, its just because of your browser cache, try clearing your browser cache. Or give it a try on different browser to confirm it is a cache issue or not.